# When do brew's source Formulas become available after release

Tags: homebrew

I did some googling and could not find an answer to this question. Say package X is updated to 1.1 on git, how long does it take brew to get that package?

```
brew update & brew upgrade X
Error: X 1.0 already installed
Already up-to-date.
```

note it is a version behind.

ruby-build was updated today but brew's version is still behind.

When or how long after, are source packages available on brew after they are released?

Comment: As soon as someone updates the formula... If you see an outdated package, go submit a PR!

Comment: For the record, the [PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/33099) for `ruby-build` has already been submitted.

Comment: ah I was not sure how it worked, but that is simple.

Comment: Homebrew is maintained by volunteers on their free time. If you think a package is outdated, please make a PR to update it.